# What's the idea behind Haskell libraries throwing exceptions

Tags: haskell

Why would a library ([`wreq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq) on a `404` for example) throw an exception instead of wrapping the result into something like `Maybe`?

Naively, I think `Maybe` would be better (compiler warning me if I'm not handling all the cases for example). Why am I wrong here?

Comment: Some will like their eithers, other will like their exceptions. I am afraid, that this is very opinionated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Haskellers do strongly strive to avoid throwing exceptions from *functions* – a function should only throw an exception in truely exceptional cases, i.e. in “this should never happen” situations like the user passing some input that's explicitly forbidden by the documentation. If pure functions regularly threw exceptions, this would be a big problem not only because the type doesn't say what one should be prepared to catch, also one *can't* catch exceptions within a pure function but only in `IO` code that calls the function. And even if you can in principle catch the exception, it may be hard to predict *where* it needs to be done because lazy evaluation can delay the point where it actually happens.

As a matter of fact, even in case of e.g. [`Wreq.get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.2.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:get), *no exception is thrown from the function*.

```
Prelude Network.Wreq> get "htt:/p/this-isn't even valid URL syntax" `seq` "Ok"
"Ok"
```

It is *the `IO` action* that throws, when you execute it:

```
Prelude Network.Wreq> get "htt:/p/this-isn't even valid URL syntax" >> pure ()
*** Exception: InvalidUrlException "htt:/p/this-isn't%20even%20valid%20URL%20syntax" "Invalid scheme"
```

Now with an `IO` action, the situation is a bit different. *Lots* of `IO` actions can have potentially very different errors in different situations that may be hard or impossible to predict, like a hard-drive crash. Catalogising all the possible errors in a suitable data type for each action would be a major undertaking, and it would be really quite cumbersome to handle every possible case or figure out which parts just to pass on. And simply wrapping the result of every single  `IO` action in `Maybe` would just lead to a similar situation as in Java where every reference can possibly null. This doesn't tell you anything, and people often wouldn't come up with sensible ways of handling this either.

This is pretty much the problem why exceptions were invented in the first place, and it holds just as well for procedural languages as it holds for Haskell (or rather, it's procedural eDSL that is `IO`). And because unlike pure functions, `IO` does have a well-defined time-sequence in its control flow, it's also pretty clear where you must do it if you need to catch some particular exception.

That's not to say it never makes sense for an `IO` action to return a `Maybe` / `Either` value that makes the possible errors explicit, just this isn't always worthwhile.

Comment: Probably one should add, that you can easily ignore the `Left` return value, if the `IO` action returned `Either` instead of throwing. But if you ignore the thrown exception, your program will crash. Ok course you can ignore the exception too, but you have to work for it more, one could argue. But as I said earlier, this will probably be very opinionated too.

Comment: FWIW, my pet theory is that the reason exceptions were invented/popular in procedural languages is that traditional procedural languages make representing, creating, and consuming sum types so painful; I have often wished for a construct in C as syntactically cheap as Either, e.g.

Comment: @Krom if you ignore a `Left` return value, you thereby turn a (hopefully) descriptive error message into an inscrutable exhaustive-patterns exception. And crash the program with _that_. If you ignore an exception thrown from the action itself, it will crash with the (again, _hopefully_) descriptive exception message.

Comment: In some cases (like an http package) I think it really would make sense to distinguish between conditions the caller almost certainly wants to handle locally (network timeout, page not found, etc.) and ones that are more likely to bubble out to a higher-level handler (exceptions thrown by another thread, nonexistent network interface, etc.).

Comment: @dfeuer I agree, but it may be hard to draw a line somewhere. And, I suspect an error-containing result type would desensitize people and they might forget about catching exceptions too.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it's definitely a judgement call. But for *many* exceptions, the only sensible thing to do in *most* applications is to let it go all the way up and kill the thread. Users are always responsible for ensuring their programs log/notify appropriately when things die unexpectedly.