# Making sure all exceptions are handled

Tags: haskell, exception

Stemming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987652/whats-the-idea-behind-haskell-libraries-throwing-exceptions), is there any way to ensure that I'm handling all exceptions could throw? Something like pattern matching exhaustiveness warning from the compiler, but for exceptions. I think this would make sense...

Comment: Possibly useful links: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:4 https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/snoyberg/general-haskell/exceptions/catching-all-exceptions

Comment: You can catch SomeException, which is the root of the exception hierarchy. There is (afaik) no programmatic way to get a list of the fine-grained exception types that might be thrown from arbitrary code

Comment: Note also strictly speaking you can't handle all exceptions, e.g. ThreadBlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar results in a thread being killed whether it's logic is surrounded by a handler or not. I'm not really sure what happens for OOM etc

Answer (score 3):

You can catch all exceptions by way of `SomeException`, but this is usually a bad idea because you also end up catching asynchronous exceptions that are [thrown to the thread](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:throwTo) from outside it.

In Haskell, it is frequent to use [asynchronous exceptions](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120142000/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/books/1230000000929/ch09.html) to trigger thread cancellations from other threads, [signal out of memory errors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:AsyncException), and the like. And it is very rare that you want to catch an asynchronous exception; they are largely unrelated to the actual logic that the thread is running. But you can still use functions like `bracket` and `finally` so that resources held by the killed thread are properly released.

There are packages like [safe-exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions) and [unliftio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.8.1/docs/UnliftIO-Exception.html) which help avoid catching asynchronous exceptions by mistake, while still providing functions like [`catchAny`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.8.1/docs/UnliftIO-Exception.html#v:catchAny) that catch other types of exceptions.

Comment: See also the video  "Async Exception Handling in Haskell" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5y8sFmCFnA